# Enable Query All Files permission

Tags: sharing, files

I see from the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_files_query_all_files.htm) that you can allow a user to query all files, even ones they don't own. I'm having trouble giving myself that permission.

I have a system admin profile, with view all data

[image]

when I go to app permission under the system admin profile, it doesn't allow me to check the Query All Files permission

[image]

What am I missing to enable this permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you cannot give profiles the permission Query All Files. You need to create a permission set with that permission, that is found under App Permissions, and assign it to the user.